# How to apply a mask to points on a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make a water simulation in JavaScript. I have something similar to [this](http://grantkot.com/MPM/Liquid.html) at the moment, made up of small points. I want to apply a mask to the points so it looks more like water but I don't know how I would go about doing this. I want to achieve an effect similar to the game "Where's my water?", basically all points that are close together appear as one blob, with a metaball-like effect. I tried Googling for a solution but didn't have any luck.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

For anyone that wants to know, I used the method shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/TscNZ/) but I only drew the gradient once on a temporary canvas and then drew that on the to real canvas using `drawImage()`, which is way faster.